# Qt: Select TreeView Item on DoubleClick Only

Tags: c++, qt, select, treeview, double-click

I want my TreeView items to be selected (highlighted) ONLY after doubleClick event. I.e., single click and right click events should be ignored, should not highlight the items in TreeView. I'm using TreeView with QStandardItemModel. I've tried:

1. Single click function on_treeViewFiles_clicked() deselects items

---

```
ui->treeViewFiles->clearSelection();
```

2. Then inside doubleClick function

---

```
void MyApp::on_treeViewFiles_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &fileidx)
```

selected an item with

```
ui->treeViewFiles->selectionModel()->select(fileidx, QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
```

3. Tried also to set current index

   `ui->treeViewFiles->setCurrentIndex(fileidx);`

Well, the code above does literaly nothing, only the highlighting is ommited.

4. I tried an eventFilter, but does not work, suggestions?

---

```
bool MyApp::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if(mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            qDebug() << "clicked";
            return true;
        }
    else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

ps. Tried the similar eventFilter with `keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Down` and it works.

[SOLVED]

Funny thing. The filter must be installed on the **treeView** for the keyboard keys and on the **TreeView->ViewPort** for the mouse clicks. So instead of

```
ui->treeViewFiles->installEventFilter(this);
```

one must install the filter on the viewport

```
ui->treeViewFiles->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

[SOLUTION 2]

Found a very simple but strong solution. First disable selection mode in constructor.

```
ui->treeViewFiles->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

Then in your doubleClick function

```
void MyApp::on_treeViewFiles_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &fileidx)
```

enable and disable selection mode of the TreeView such that

```
ui->treeViewFiles->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
ui->treeViewFiles->selectionModel()->select(fileidx, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
ui->treeViewFiles->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

Comment: I guess you could write an event filter to filter out single click events and only pass through double click events (double click being two single click events happening within a certain time-frame - which you' probably need to keep track of yourself)...

Comment: Yes, I tried an event filter as well, but did not manage to make it work. Do you perhaps have a code example for this case? Examples from Qt Doc are not really helpfull.

Comment: don't have an example off the top op my head, but I've used event filters to do similar things in the past - don't see why it couldn't work.

Comment: I have added an eventFilter, which I've tried, to the question. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Vito Do not add to the title SOLVED, in SO to indicate that a question has been resolved you must mark an answer as correct, if you have solved your problem then we invite you to publish it and mark it as correct. check the [tour] so you know the dynamics of the site.

Comment: @ eyllanesc Thanks for edit. ps. I cannot mark the question as correct, only answers, but here is no answers - I've answered myself after 6 hours of trial and error.